# how to put an image on the border of a linear layout in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to put an image of a bookmark on the bottom border of a linear layout. Basically, it is a bookmark button type and my linear layout contains a question and image is a bookmark button. When the user clicks it, the question will be saved. But how can I add the image on the border of linear layout? This is the layout that I want to design.

[image]

Can someone tell me how to do this? What will be the xml code for it.

Comment: try to use ... `marginTop` in negative for your bookmark view...

Comment: What is your obsession with "..."? You should have used a ".", "," or ";".

Comment: About the question- It's off-topic as you are asking for code without showing any evidence that you actually tried it.

Comment: I have no idea.. ..how to start it.. ..thats why i am asking it.. .

Comment: LinearLayout will not allow children to overlap. Use other layouts.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding *if you want to make overlapping view (like the bookmark one, as depicted in your question), you should use **`ConstraintLayout`** rather than using **`LinearLayout`** or **`RelativeLayout`** or any other layout as because by using **`ConstraintLayout`** you can easily create overlapping views and use them.*

The below code should solve your problem, if you have some understanding of the **`ConstraintLayout`**.

*1] activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--  res/layout/activity_main.xml  -->

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1.  Who was the first prime minister of India?"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="25dp"
        android:paddingEnd="25dp"
        android:paddingBottom="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_for_bookmark_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        android:contentDescription="Bookmark Icon"
        android:tint="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

*2] drawable_for_bookmark_view.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--  res/drawable/drawable_for_bookmark_view.xml  -->

<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:color="#000"
        android:width="3dp" />

    <corners
        android:radius="7dp" />

</shape>
```

*3] Also, add this dependency of **`ConstraintLayout`** in the build.gradle (Module:app) file; within the dependencies block, as:*

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
}
```

***Screenshot (of the above code):***

[image]

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#000">
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_plus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
```